# How this two spliting method differs in bash?

Tags: bash, split

I am struggling earlier with a string splitting in bash. After some search i have found two method of doing this that split a string and make an array of that splitted parts.

But when i am printing them i am getting different result.

```
a="hello,hi,hola"
```

**Method 1:**

```
IFS=',' read -ra arr <<< "$a"
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```
hello hi hola
```

**Method 2:**

```
arr=$(echo $a | tr "," "\n")
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

**Output:**

```
hello
hi
hola
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: In your method 2, `arr` is not an array. You need: `arr=( $(echo $a | tr "," "\n") )` to make it an array. Then you'll run into problems if you have consecutive space characters, or glob characters. Use Method 1, or even better, `IFS=, read -r -d '' -a arr < <(printf '%s,\0' "$a")`, which is the canonical way of splitting a string in Bash. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886 .

Comment: You can write it as an answer with nice formatting so that fellow users might be helped. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your method 2, `arr` is not an array. You need:

```
arr=( $(echo $a | tr "," "\n") )
```

to make it an array.

With this method you'll run into problems if you have consecutive space characters, or glob characters. Use Method 1, or even better,

```
IFS=, read -r -d '' -a arr < <(printf '%s,\0' "$a")
```

which is the canonical way of splitting a string in Bash. See [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886) .

Comment: By the way, what's the data type of arr in my method 2?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque in your method 2, `arr` is just a string. Check it with `declare -p arr`.